# How to find all non-dictionary words in a file in bash/zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm trying to find all words in a file that don't exist in the dictionary. If I look for a single word the following works

```
b=ther; look $b | grep -i "^$b$" | ifne -n echo $b => ther
b=there; look $b | grep -i "^$b$" | ifne -n echo $b => [no output]
```

However if I try to run a "while read" loop

```
while read a; do look $a | grep -i "^$a$" | ifne -n echo "$a"; done < <(tr -s '[[:punct:][:space:]]' '\n' <lotr.txt |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

The output seems to contain all (?) words in the file. Why doesn't this loop only output non-dictionary words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding ifne**

If `stdin` is non-empty, `ifne -n` reprints `stdin` to `stdout`.  From the manpage:

```
   -n   Reverse operation. Run the command if the standard input is empty

        Note that if the standard input is not empty, it is passed through
        ifne in this case.
```

`strace` on `ifne` confirms this behavior.

**Alternative**

Perhaps, as an alternative:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash -e
  2 
  3 export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
  4 
  5 while read a; do
  6     look "$a" | grep -qi "^$a$" || echo "$a"
  7 done < <(
  8     tr -s '[[:punct:][:space:]]' '\n' < lotr.txt \
  9     | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' \
 10     | sort -u \
 11     | grep .
 12 )
```

Comment: `tr [A-Z] [a-z]` does not reliably do what you think it does. What happens when there's a single letter file?